# FCM notification not opening intended activity Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am trying to get notification generated by FCM console and I am receiving them but I am unable to override `onMessageReceived` of FirebaseMessagingService. Don't know what I am doing wrong.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService** class responsible for handling notifications:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "FROM:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        //Check if the message contains data
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        //Check if the message contains notification

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Mesage body:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getData());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Dispay the notification
     * @param body
     */
    private void sendNotification(String body , Map<String,String> data) {

//        int finalSecId = Integer.parseInt((String) data.get("sec_id"));
//        int sec = Integer.parseInt((String) data.get("sec"));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, InsuranceActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //Set sound of notification
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.login_meter)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText((String) data.get("sec_id")+ " "+(String) data.get("sec"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /*ID of notification*/, notifiBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And Inside Application tag

```
<service android:name=".Fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".Fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: you need to send DATA instead of Notification from server and at Message data you have to show NOTIFICATION

Comment: Actually the data is sent from the FCM console but I am unable to handle it in a service onMessageReceived is not triggered and I am unable to see the results for specific tag in logs as well

Comment: then in fcm console, use ADVANCED option and send data in key-value pair. After that you can receive data in OnMessageReceived()

Comment: doing that as well

Comment: actually in foreground its triggered but in background it isnt

Comment: you have to use DATA paylod for background/foreground state, and use remoteMessage.getData() to show value in notification

Comment: So, you are receiving notification both in foreground and background, but the background notification isn't opening **InsuranceActivity**, rather it always opens the MainActivity... is it the case?

Comment: @Sudip yes this is the case

Comment: Okay, I will try to write an answer in a while. Are you only using firebase console to send notification or also using firebase API?

Comment: I am having an API its working fine with both cases just require client side solution

Comment: If you are using API, you can try the **method 2** of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39330797/5829624

Comment: The idea is: send a custom_value with 'click_action' key inside the notification payload. use that custom_value inside an intent-filter of your Activity (which you want to open). and you should be good to go.

Comment: My activities are dynamic depending upon the key value pair showing which section to move towards e.g  `$fields = array(
            'to' => $token,
            'notification' => array('title' => 'Motors City', 'body' => $message),
            'data' => array(
                'sec_id' => $secID,
                'sec' => $sec,
                'extra1'=>$extra1,
                'extra2'=>$extra2
            )
        );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending #Sudip Podder comments and #Ratilal Chopda answer
Follow these steps:

**Step1:**

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".SplashActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Step2:**

I am using php at server so you need to adjust things the way you like but in notification payload add  `"click_action" : ".SplashActivity"`

```
 $fields = array(
            'to' => $token,
            'notification' => array(
                'title' => 'Motors City',
                'body' => $message,
                "click_action" => ".AppSplash",

            ),
            'data' => array(
                'sec_id' => $secID,
                'sec' => $sec,
                'extra1'=>$extra1,
                'extra2'=>$extra2
            )
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key=' . $server_key,
            'Content-Type:application/json'
        );
```

**Step3:**
In Oncreate of your `SplashActivity`

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
  Log.d(TAG,bundle.toString);
}}
```

and you are done

Comment: Nicely written (y)

Answer (score 2):

**There are two types of FCM**

notification Messages: Sending a payload with this message type triggers onMessageReceived() only when your app is in foreground.

data Messages: Sending a payload with only this specific message type triggers onMessageReceived() regardless if your app is in foreground/background.

Reference:[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem of handling the notifications from FCM.

First we have to understand that there are 2 types of notifications.

1. Notification - It will trigger when your app is not in foreground and generate a notification. If you click on it then it will open the launcher activity.
2. Data notification - This one is used to parse the data and it is received in background as well as foreground. So you can build a custom notification based on the data provided in the data object by the FCM Push.

   ```
    Map<String ,String> dataMap = remoteMessage.getData();
   ```

   Here i created a simple Map with key value pairs. Now i can receive the title of the notification in the data object and make a simple notification with a custom intent.

I personally use a context object to determine if the app is in foreground or background. Based on that i decide if i have to show the notification or just update the data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are having Notification in notification type, which triggers Notification Default,and Just open the app on the click of the notification.

So you need to change server side code from notification type to data type.
And try to get Message from

```
`remoteMessage.getData()`  not from `remoteMessage.getNotification()`
```

if you want to manage click of the notification use data type notification.to understand more about this types go through this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: I think your have read the code its already mentioned in the code

Comment: in your code intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: instead of setFlags use addFlags

Comment: did you get the solution.

Comment: trying its something to deal with the intent in main root activity

Comment: did you getting notification on notification bar

Comment: yes im getting it the only problem is while the applicaiton is in foreground it works well in background state I am unbale to handle data

Comment: did you try addFlags instead of setFlags

Comment: yup tried to did so but its isnt the issue the issue is that there is different handling for backgorund notificaiton